# What is SQL's role in creating database applications

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I want to want to find out the part that SQL plays in GUI database application development and how this interacts with the standard GUI functionality in Apex.

Comment: Are we talking Oracle-Apex or Force.com Apex?

Comment: @JNevill Oracle Apex.

Comment: I have updated the tags to reflect that.

Comment: @JNevill  want to find out the part that SQL plays in GUI database application development and how this interacts with the standard GUI functionality in Apex

Answer (score 1):

From a high-level, APEX includes many components which you can include in your application - a chart, a grid, a report, a tree, a calendar, etc.  The source of the data is provided by you - it could be as simple as a single table which you specify, or it could be a SQL query that you provide - as simple or complex as you wish.  At runtime, the SQL you provide will be parsed, executed and the results fetched by the APEX engine.  The result will then be rendered appropriately for the given component.

In [this Oracle Magazine article](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/see-better-results) (which you can practice for free on apex.oracle.com), in the "Custom Data Visualizations" section, you'll see a SQL query with a number of UNION operators, which is the data source for the multi-series chart shown further down the page.

In APEX 18.1 and later, the source for several components (report, chart, calendar) can be a SQL query against your local database objects, or it can also be a REST Enabled SQL Service or a Web Source (e.g., JSON data feed over HTTP).